# Courier won't start because /usr/sbin/pop3d doesn't exist

Tags: server, upgrade

My courier-pop and courier-imap servers won't start. I'm using an old Ubuntu 6.06 box. I did an `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` 2 days ago, which may have messed things up (there were a few errors). In any case, `/usr/sbin/pop3d` no longer exists. This is a file that the courier-pop startup script calls.

I always back-up the machine fully before doing an update and when I extracted the backup to see if I could restore that file from there, the *backed-up-copy* is present but it has 0 file size and no permissions. I'm stuck. I didn't realize an update / upgrade could corrupt things.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working. Posting here for posterity.

I manually copied over courier and postfix files from `/usr/lib` and then re-created the symlinks from `/usr/sbin` and `/usr/bin` to those files. The files were actually correctly backed-up; it's just that the ones with filesize 0 were symlinks and I checked them while my backup was still extracting.